# LavaLamp--set 'current' when using template for several pages

Tags: jquery, lavalamp

I use vBulletin for several or our pages within our website (home, blog, forum, gallery, tutorials and FAQ) and are currently using a lavalamp (http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/).

I have been trying, unsuccessfully, for several weeks to figure out how to dynamically set the 'current' class depending upon which page you are on.  Below are a couple examples of my failed attempts--I have verified the code works, in that, I am able to get to the correct li.. but the addClass or removeClass, just isn't working. I have tried using the menu's ID as the selector, placing the script in several different places, making it a function and calling the function with the lavalamp inialization code... Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

**First Attempt:**

```
<!--BEGIN LAVA MENU-->
    <ul class="lavaLamp" id="lavaMM">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/market/">Market</a></li>
        <li><a href="/content.php/475-the-daily-buzz">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="/forum/forum.php">Forum</a></li>
        <li><a href="/gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="/forum/forumdisplay.php/439-Scrap-Orchard-University">Tutorials</a></li>
        <li><a href="/staff/">Staff</a></li>
        <li><a href="/forum/faq.php">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="/market/support/">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
<!--END LAVA MENU-->


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#lavaMM').lavaLamp({
        fx: 'backout', 
        speed: 700,
        click: function(event, menuItem) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    var fullURL = document.URL;
    var splitURL = fullURL.split('/', 4);
    if (splitURL[3] == 'content.php') {
        $('ul.lavaLamp li:eq(2)').addClass('current');
    }
    else if (splitURL[3] == 'forum') {
            $('ul.lavaLamp li:eq(3)').addClass('current');
    } 
    else if (splitURL[3] == 'gallery') {
            $('ul.lavaLamp li:eq(4)').addClass('current');
    } 
});
</script>
```

**Second Attempt:**

```
<!--BEGIN LAVA MENU-->
    <ul class="lavaLamp" id="lavaMM">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/market/">Market</a></li>
        <li class="current"><a href="/content.php/475-the-daily-buzz">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="current"><a href="/forum/forum.php">Forum</a></li>
        <li class="current"><a href="/gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="/forum/forumdisplay.php/439-Scrap-Orchard-University">Tutorials</a></li>
        <li><a href="/staff/">Staff</a></li>
        <li><a href="/forum/faq.php">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="/market/support/">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
<!--END LAVA MENU-->

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#lavaMM').lavaLamp({
        fx: 'backout', 
        speed: 700,
        click: function(event, menuItem) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    var fullURL = document.URL;
    var splitURL = fullURL.split('/', 4);
    if (splitURL[3] == 'content.php') {
        $('ul.lavaLamp li:eq(3)').removeClass('current');
        $('ul.lavaLamp li:eq(4)').removeClass('current');
    }
    else if (splitURL[3] == 'forum') {
            $('ul.lavaLamp li:eq(2)').removeClass('current');
        $('ul.lavaLamp li:eq(4)').removeClass('current');
    } 
    else if (splitURL[3] == 'gallery') {
        $('ul.lavaLamp li:eq(2)').removeClass('current');
            $('ul.lavaLamp li:eq(3)').removeClass('current');
    } 
});
</script>
```

**Third Attempt:**

```
<!--BEGIN LAVA MENU-->
    <ul class="lavaLamp" id="lavaMM">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/market/">Market</a></li>
        <li><a href="/content.php/475-the-daily-buzz">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="/forum/forum.php">Forum</a></li>
        <li><a href="/gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="/forum/forumdisplay.php/439-Scrap-Orchard-University">Tutorials</a></li>
        <li><a href="/staff/">Staff</a></li>
        <li><a href="/forum/faq.php">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="/market/support/">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
<!--END LAVA MENU-->



<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fullURL = document.URL;
    var splitURL = fullURL.split('/', 4);
    if (splitURL[3] == 'content.php') {
        $('ul.lavaLamp li:eq(2)').each(function() {
                    $(this).addClass('current');
        });
    }
    else if (splitURL[3] == 'forum') {
            $('ul.lavaLamp li:eq(3)').each(function() {
                    $(this).addClass('current');
            });
    } 
    else if (splitURL[3] == 'gallery') {
            $('ul.lavaLamp li:eq(4)').each(function() {
                    $(this).addClass('current');
            });
    } 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the file `lavalamp.js` 
replace the `o` with:

```
o = $.extend({ fx: "linear", speed: 500, classes: 'current', click: function(){} }, o || {});
$current = o.classes;
```

**call the function:**

```
 $(function() { $("#menu_main").lavaLamp({ fx: "backout", speed: 700 ,classes : 'current_page_item'})});
```